# How to flat list in a list containing multiple data types in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[image]

I have this kind of list I want to flat this into a single list how can I do this task please help??

Comment: Please post the lists as code so that users can copy and paste it to try it out

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty list. Iterate through your original, and use either `extend` or `append`

```
new_list = []
for item in original_list:
    if isinstance(item, list):
       new_list.extend(item)
    else:
       new_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    features = list(itertools.chain(*(i if isinstance(i, list) else (i,) for i in features)))
```

Done using this.